# Why do we have to put api in front of routes?

Tags: api, express

I am learning express and the http methods, but I cannot find any documentation on it. Is /api/value just for the json data, like an address just for that data? Just any extra info on it would be appreciated. Like what exactly does it do and if there is any documentation from express about it. Or is this a global term used in urls throughout frameworks and the internet?

For example:

`app.get('/api/jackets'(req, res) => {res.send('logic')})`

Why do we need to add the api before jackets and what does it do?

Comment: You don't have to, it's just a convention (with very good reasons for it).

Comment: " Just any extra info on it would be appreciated." - extra info **on what, exactly?** - it sounds like you're seeking guidance for RESTful web-service design...

Comment: Just asking about the term itself.

Comment: “The terms itself” - what term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/api` request is not required, but putting a prefix in front of the API requests such as:

```
/api
```

or, in some cases including a version number:

```
/api/v1
```

Allows you to use the same web server for more than one type of request because the `/api` prefix uniquely identifies each API request as an API request and it can easily be routed to where you handle API requests.  You could have plain web page requests from a browser served by the same web server.  While, you don't have to use such a prefix, using it gives you the most flexibility in how you deploy and use your server.

Similarly, putting the version in the prefix such as `/api/v1` allows you to evolve your API in the future in a non-backward-compatible way by adding a new version designation without breaking prior API clients (you support both versions at the same time - at least for a transition period).

Comment: The problem with `/api/v1`-style versioning is that it doesn't easily accommodate versioning different areas of the API separately from others, effectively forcing you into cloning your entire web-service into a new version every time you make a breaking change. Ultimately, there are no easy solutions to versioning under RESTful guidelines.

Comment: @Dai - There are pros/cons to `/api/v1` versioning.  I would say you shouldn't be making breaking changes to a portion of your API without some defenses like `/api/v1`.  And, you don't have to clone much in order to add a new version.  In fact, you could use the entire same router as before with one new method override for the changed method.  The v2 implementation could literally be only a couple lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary, it's used only for a better understanding

Comment: Please expand and elaborate on what you mean by “it's used only for a better understanding”.